# Should I add XML comments in DTO models or entity models

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, comments, documentation-generation, dto

I have 2 models, DTOs and database models (entities) that map to the database.

I usually put XML comments above the properties to describe what are they for.

```
class MyEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Some summary
    /// </summary>
    public string SomeThing { get; set; }
}
```

Should I put these comments in my DTOs or entities?

Comment: "*I usually put XML comments above the properties to describe what are they for*". I wish you wouldn't. If the name of the property doesn't describe what it's for, fix the name, rather than polluting the code with noisy comments.

Comment: @DavidArno What about examples of values that it can contain, for example, I have my property named `Symbol` and user doesn't know what kind of symbol, maybe it should be a symbol in ISO format or something.

Comment: @Konrad then maybe it should be called IsoSymbol?

Comment: @KevinVanDyck maybe it should

Comment: As @KevinVanDyck says, don't have a property called `Symbol`; have a name that describes what sort of symbol and or what it's used for.

Comment: Yes, please put them on the DTOs - those should then be parsed by a documentation generator (such as Swagger/Swashbuckle) for your API consumers to reference. Include the seealso and example tags for the same reason - show the usage. On entities, eh, not a lot of valid in my opinion unless you're pulling data dictionary metadata from somewhere and decorating them with that on (re)generation.

Comment: @DavidArno If there is a 'Name' string field, a comment explaining the format (First then Last, Last comma First, First Middle Last, etc) would be helpful.

Comment: If the Entity class is the best source of truth about the nature of the data, then I'd put the XML explanations there. If the DTO classes are just mappers w/ some props that are the same name as the Entity class, then you can skip the comments there UNLESS the mapping does some transformation, like a DTO that has a Name prop that combines FirstName and LastName from the Entity. In that case, a comment on the Name prop explaining how its composed would be useful.

Answer (score -3):

If the DTO and the entity are quit similar you shouldn't duplicate the documentation but you can reference the entity from the DTO and its properties.

With the inheritdoc tag:

```
/// <summary>
/// Some summary
/// </summary>
class MyEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Some summary
    /// </summary>
    public string SomeThing { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Some summary
    /// </summary>
    public int SomeThingElse { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Some summary <see cref="MyEntity"/>
/// </summary>
class MyDTO
{
    /// <inheritdoc cref="MyEntity.SomeThing"/>
    public string SomeThing { get; set; }
}
```

The feature [Add a way to inherit documentation  #313](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/313) i'm using .net framework version 4.6.1.

Isn't well documented on dotnet just for a few petition in the former link, but with some extensions or nuget pacakge you can used too if your version dotnet doesn't supported.

- Free [SandCastle](https://tunnelvisionlabs.github.io/SHFB/docs-master/SandcastleBuilder/html/79897974-ffc9-4b84-91a5-e50c66a0221d.htm)
- Free this you can install from nuget package [inheritdoc.io](https://www.inheritdoc.io/)
- Free trial [Ghost Doc](https://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx)

Comment: The "Gets or Sets" language looks unnecessary and verbose. The comment adds nothing above what we can already tell from the code.

Comment: It is true the former answer wasn't the correct answer not even close, excuse me.